# pod install fails in react-native

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

Running pod install from the root project of my library is giving me the below error:-

```
➜ app git:(master) ✗ pod install                                 
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
```

when i run `pod install` from inside <Project_root>/ios then i am getting the below error:-

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- app/node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.

 #  from app/ios/Podfile:3
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods'
 #  require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
```

Comment: @BasvanderLinden - I have installed CocaPods using sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: In that case try to uninstall cocoapods (if you have multiple versions uninstall them all). Then reinstall: `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Then pod install inside the ios directory should work.

Comment: Have you tried ye'ol `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`?

Comment: did all of this but no luck.

Comment: you should always run `pod install` inside `/ios`. what does your `Podfile` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should run `pod install` inside the `ios` directory where the `Podifle` is located.

```
cd ios
pod install
```